# Dissolve or disintegrate part of mesh while it is animating?

Tags: animation, objects, armature, vertices, vertex-groups

Is it possible to dissolve each vertice of a part of a mesh while it is on the course of its own animation?

I.E have an animation for the mesh and have an animation for the disintegration and have the disintegration say remove half of the mesh while it is animating on its other animation (the transformation, rotation, scaling of its other animation that is not disintegration)?

Then I can make multiple disintegration animations, say 4 total and each will disintegrate 1/4th of the whole mesh, and play all 4 at the same time of its other animation to see the whole mesh, not just part, disintegrate while the single mesh is moving over the course of its animation?

Basically dissolve the mesh without having it jump to some pose before it can dissolve. I.e. it can be in any animation pose when it can start dissolving.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the *Build* modifier.

The build modifier erases your mesh, then animates it being "re-built" face-by-face.  Just add a Build modifier to your object, set the *Start* frame and frame *Duration* to the desired amounts.  Then check *Reversed* to have it progressively take away geometry instead of building it from empty.

[image]

To get a more dissolve-like effect I would also check *Randomize*, this makes it randomly choose faces to take away, instead of sequentially doing connected adjacent faces.  Here is a side by side comparison, with Randomize checked on the left and unchecked on the right.

[image]

Comment: How can I have this start at any time during an animation that does not have any dissolve modifier?

i.e. say a player mesh is going about its idle_walk_run cycle. It will have its bones in different relative locations

but when a button is pressed all players are forced to run this dissolve animation (they all have the same skeleton) no matter where they are in the idle_walk_run cycle.

so some will dissolve from idle position, some will dissolve with their legs out in front of them as they are walking, or some in a full sprint?

Comment: is this possible? I have seen in a game such as Halo where someone is shot with a laser, no matter how the ragdoll is posed on hit impact of the laser (instant death), only then will the dissolve start at all bone locations

Comment: @nmm131  You mean you want to do this in the game engine?  (You didn't mention that in your question.)  The animation position doesn't matter though, just put the Build modifier after the Armature modifier.

Comment: I will compile everything in a game engine. But how would I trigger the build and re-build modifier for a mesh that is in animation?

do I bake the build as a material and then apply the material to the mesh object? or is there a way to conduct this with a linear plane or sphere that would overlap the mesh to induce the dissolve?

Comment: @nmm131 I don't know, I'm not a BGE expert.  I'd ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a truly powerful control over your animation and manipulate your mesh, there is a bit cumbersome, but well-suited approach to this: Shape Keys.

Check this out: https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys.html?highlight=shape%20keys